# White space displaying on right side webpage on small devices like iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone

there's a small white strip displaying on the right side of my webpage when viewed on iPhone. this has been asked on SO before but after trying a handful of solutions and debugging i still can't work it out.

can anyone work out which element is the root of problem?

source is http://buildtrumpwall.com

screenshot: http://s23.postimg.org/tkofnnere/i_Phone_Screen_Shot.jpg

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Not everyone uses an iphone to check it. What did you try?

Comment: thanks. just added link now. tried fooling around with all container widths, the html and body element widths, specific small-screen viewport options. can't seem to make it go away

Answer (score 0):

its the `min-width` css attribute on your `banner` element

```
#banner {
    margin-top: -180px;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

remove that and it'll stop pushing your screen out past the screen boundaries

Comment: thanks so much! this solved it! will have to go back to drawing board to make sure i understand what's going on

Comment: edit...this appeared to work on dev tools (inspect element). however, when i posted live site the whitespace has re-appeared on the right of the screen. any other ideas?